# I want a plotly dropdown to filter a dataframe by a column unique values

Tags: python, pandas, filter, plotly, dropdown

Good evening!

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'distance': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'Speed': [1, 2, 3, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3],
    'Lap': ['Lap 1', 'Lap 1', 'Lap 1', 'Lap 2', 'Lap 2', 'Lap 2', 'Lap 3', 'Lap 3', 'Lap 3']
})
```

I want to plot it using plotly, using a dropdown filtering the lines plotted, by the column "lap" unique values `( 'Lap 1', 'Lap 2', 'Lap 3')`.

Note: I cannot use Dash due to Flask restrictions.

I was able to do so by writing a bunch of `Trues` and `Falses` but the dataframe is dynamic so a static solution is not gonna work (it can have more rows, it can be scrambled etc)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'distance': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'Speed': [1, 2, 3, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3],
    'Lap': ['Lap 1', 'Lap 1', 'Lap 1', 'Lap 2', 'Lap 2', 'Lap 2', 'Lap 3', 'Lap 3', 'Lap 3']
})

data = []
for lap in df['Lap'].unique():
    data.append(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df[df['Lap']==lap]['distance'],
            y=df[df['Lap']==lap]['Speed'],
            name=lap
        )
    )

layout = go.Layout(
    title='Speed vs Distance by Lap',
    xaxis=dict(title='Distance'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Speed')
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label=lap,
                    method="update",
                    args=[{"visible": [lap == trace.name for trace in fig.data]},
                          {"title": "Speed vs Distance for " + lap}]
                ) for lap in df['Lap'].unique()
            ],
            direction="down",
            showactive=True,
            x=1,
            xanchor="right",
            y=1.2,
            yanchor="top"
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Sir! It was right what I needed! The documentation examples were good but I had difficulty digesting the definitions of the functions args.